# Join deletion with same syntax in mysql and h2

Tags: mysql, h2, rdbms

I have a production database in mysql and do some Junit tests in H2.
I am struggling to find a syntax that would both work in tests and production to delete records in 2 tables.
SQL queries are sent to the database using

```
jdbctemplate.update(sqlQuery, queryArgs);
```

So far I have found queries that work on mysql but not on H2 and vice versa.

I have 2 tables : requests and responses which have 2 columns in common datetime and milisec. The couple (datetime, milisec) is a primary key on requests, there can be several responses for the same couple.

I want to delete the responses that matches some of the requests.

This requests works fine with my sql but not with H2 :

```
DELETE r.*
FROM responses AS r NATURAL JOIN Call_requests AS s
WHERE -- criteria on call_requests table
```

The closest I have come with would be

```
DELETE FROM responses
where (datetime, milisec) in 
(select datetime, milisec from requests where -- criteria)
```

this upper version works with mysql not with h2, where as the following with parentheses around the tuple  is the reverse (works with h2, not mysql)

```
DELETE FROM responses
where (datetime, milisec) in 
(select (datetime, milisec) from requests where -- criteria)
```

Comment: Oh, `r.*` works !?!? I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: I wonder what MySQL thinks `.*` means in this context.

Comment: Not a lot of answers or other comments on this one... I have reengineered the data base to have a unique index key that can make the join between the 2 tables. Solved the problem...

Comment: @PrDP Hi. Your edit dropping a tag really made no difference whatsoever & should not have been approved. Moreover it is not appropriate to add tags just because they technically include topics of (either one or of multiple) other tags; it is better to tag as specifically as possible. Please read about editing under approval at  [help] & by googling about that with 'stackexchange'. Please make substantive edits.

Comment: Hi! I have no idea about H2 but you can try one more syntax working for MySQL:
DELETE responses FROM responses JOIN Call_requests ON Call_requests.Field_name = responses.Field_name WHERE <your_criteria>

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a slightly different approach since H2 and MySQL handle tuple comparisons slightly differently.

Instead of trying to use a tuple comparison (i.e., comparing `(datetime, milisec)` from **requests** to `(datetime, milisec)` from **responses**), you could do separate comparisons for `datetime` and `milisec`.

To delete matching records from two tables, **requests** and **responses**, using the same SQL code for both MySQL and H2 databases this should work:

```
DELETE FROM responses
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM requests 
    WHERE responses.datetime = requests.datetime 
    AND responses.milisec = requests.milisec 
    -- add more criteria here if you need
)
```

Here we're removing entries from `responses` if there's at least one entry in `requests` with the same `datetime` and `milisec`.